# Custom Identity User class with one-to-many relationship creates extra column in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity, .net-5, entity-framework-core-migrations

I'm using `ASP.NET Core Identity` along with `Entity Framework Core` on `.NET 5`, using a code first approach with a postgresql database.

I am trying to extend the identity classes like this

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public ICollection<UserLogin> Logins { get; set; }
}

public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public sealed class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim,UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

However, when I run migrations, the tables that it produces look like this -

[image]

Notice that an extra column `UserId1` has been created.

I would expect it to recognize that the `UserLogin.User` navigation's `Id` should be correspond to the `IdentityUserLogin.UserId` property (according to the conventions laid out by MS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key).

I have also tried overriding `IdentityUserLogin.UserId` but without luck:

```
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public override int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know that I could probably do a workaround like specifying the mapping manually for these tables, but Id rather figure out how to use the migration tool along with my extended identity classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your `UserLogin` model has a `UserId` property inherited from `IdentityUserLogin`.
2. According to the default `Identity` data model, there is already a one-to-many relationship between `IdentityUser` and `IdentityUserLogin`, and the `UserId` property in `IdentityUserLogin` serves as the foreign key for this relationship.
3. The `Identity` database is generated based on the default data model and any extension you make to those models. Therefore, the `AspNetUserLogins` table already has a `UserId` column serving as a foreign key to `AspNetUsers` table.
4. It is up to you whether or not you want navigation properties for the already existing relationships.

Now, you have added navigation properties, but you didn't tell EF that you want these navigations to base on the existing relationship. Therefore, EF is considering this as a new one-to-many relation and creating a new foreign key column `UserId1` in `AspNetUserLogins` table.

In the `OnModelCreating` method just tell EF that your added navigations should base on the already existing foreign key -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>(e =>
    {
        e.HasMany(p => p.Logins)
        .WithOne(p => p.User)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId);  // inherited from IdentityUserLogin
    });
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makese a lot of sense, thank you! I guess i expected it to work as if the classes were non identity classes, i tested it without the identity inheritance and it worked as expected. I can make this change and keep this in mind for the other navigation properties i plan on adding.

Answer (score 4):

`IdentityUserLogin` already has a UserId property which will turn into UserId columnn
[IdentityUserLogin SourceCode](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUserLogin.cs)

When you add the User property to UserLogin, EF will also add a UserId property (Like you pointed out in your question).
And that is then turned into a column  *usually* called `UserId`

In order to prevent duplicate property names Ef has to make *your* `UserId` different by adding the suffix `1`